# "Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a problem with inserting Data into Database. Let's say I have a controller named HeroController and I want to create a new hero object and insert it to my database as a new hero.

My controller contains the following method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
//        return response()->json([
//            'name' => 'Abigail',
//            'state' => 'CA'
//        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
    }
    public function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data[password]),
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->isMethod('put');

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json($usere, 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My routes.php file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@create');
```

This is the error that i got. Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::attendance(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected". I am new to laravel.

Comment: where is `array $data` coming from ? in `create` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a get request to call `create` function.

```
Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@create');
```

So, you are not passing any data to that controller. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to change the visibility of `create` and `validator`:

```
protected function create(array $data)
```

And the validator method:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
```

Then you'll want to change your `/users/create` route to a `post` and to use the `store` method:

```
Route::post('/users/create', 'UserController@store');
```

In your `UserController` update your `store` method to:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate the request
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()
        ->json(422,$validator->errors()->messages());
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    return response()->json($user, 201);
}
```

If you need some sort of form to register or create a user, add an additional method in your controller:

```
public function register()
{
    return view('user.register');
}
```

Then define another `get` route:

```
Route::get('/users/register', 'UserController@register');
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get a JSON reply and not a view? (register method)

Comment: Why would you need a json response to display a form to register users? The json response would be from your store method.

Answer (score 0):

```php
 Route::delete('/file/{id}','FileController@destroy')->name('deletefile');
```

Hope it will be helpful